# Any app which can transform .vtt to .srt?

Tags: subtitle, webvtt, srt

Are there any apps which can transform from `.vtt` to `.srt` format? I tried subtitleeditor which doesn't have support for `.vtt`. If anybody does know of any specific app which can be used to do the same, please share.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org) for this:

```sh
ffmpeg -i file.vtt file.srt
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I checked my VTT file against a validator and it's valid -- this command just spits out an empty SRT file. "Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)". ffmpeg version n6.0.

Answer (score 1):

With subconv you can do it. To install it, execute the following commands in a command prompt or terminal window:

```
git clone https://github.com/Smile4ever/subconv
cd subconv
npm update
npm install
```

To use:

```
node index.js -f srt file.vtt > file.srt
```

You will need to install Node.js. The installation steps for Node.js are different for every platform, but the general rule is:

- Windows: download the installer from https://nodejs.org/en/download/
- Mac: download the installer from https://nodejs.org/en/download/
- Linux: download and install the package from the repositories.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this software.

Comment: I will have to check it, currently having issues with nodejs (there is a transition thing happening in Debian to make it current with nodejs upstream), unless that is not done, wouldn't be able to use nodejs. I have ancient nodejs 10 :(

Comment: I suppose that Nodejs 10 should be fine to use subconv.